# Maven force a specific Java version while having a main class

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I want my code to compile under Java 8 or above.
But to use so, as far as I understand, I have to use compiler plugin.

However I want my final JAR to be executed, which I can tell the main class.
It seems an option in JAR plugin. So how can I use both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple maven plugins together, each of them doing a different job. You can specify version like below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
            <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can't create runnable jar using `maven-jar-plugin`. To do so, you'll need `maven-assembly-plugin` or `maven-shade-plugin`. 
You can see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-shade-plugin/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was all I am looking for.

Comment: Sukhpal Singh can you tell why you are referencing such an ancient version of the maven-compiler-plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise It was just an example. You can reference a new version or don't specify it and maven will pick latest(not recommended though)

Comment: Updated maven-compiler-plugin version